# Get text from GtkEntry with property "text"

Tags: c, gtk3, gnome

I need to get text from a bunch of GtkEntries when a button click. I create a custom struct and pass it to the button's click callback. I don't want to use `gtk_entry_get_text(*entry)` since I need to pass the struct of GtkEntries.

```c
typedef struct{
    const gchar* id1;
    const gchar* id2;
} EntryData;

static void on_click(GtkWidget *widget,
                         gpointer data) {

    EntryData* d= (EntryData*)data;
    printf ("Entry contents: %s\n", d->id1);
    printf ("Entry contents: %s\n", d->id2);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    // ....
    GtkButton *button_create_hp;
    GtkEntry *entry_id1;
    GtkEntry *entry_id2;


    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

   //...... widget and object initialization


    gtk_entry_set_text(entry_ssd,"");

    gchar *strval1="sl";
    gchar *strval2="sl";

    g_object_get(G_OBJECT (entry_id1), "text", &strval1,NULL);
    g_object_get(G_OBJECT (entry_id2), "text", &strval2,NULL);

    EntryData entryData={
            .id1= strval1,
            .id2= strval2
    };


    g_signal_connect (button_create_hp, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_click),&entryData);


    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried with `g_object_get_property (G_OBJECT (entry_id), "text", &val);`

In both cases changed values not printed when the button clicked.
Can you suggest a proper way to get values and pass it from *GtkEntries*

Comment: Why `WIData* d=`? Shouldn't it be `EntryData* d=`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a mistake. corrected @KeineLust

Comment: This code seems correct to me, take a look in deeper in the _//...... widget and object initialization_ part

Comment: Well, there is a typo in `gchar *strval1="sl";` (is redeclared) but it will not compile in this case.

Comment: Yep. I renamed some variable to make that clear. In original no compilation or syntax error. @KeineLust

Comment: I initialized the widgets from *glade* file. I didn't mention here because it is not necessary. Code works well when I get text with `gtk_entry_get_text(*entry)` @KeineLust

Comment: Try `g_object_get(entry_id1,` instead of `g_object_get(G_OBJECT (entry_id1),`

Comment: Do you call `g_object_get(G_OBJECT (entry_id1), "text"...` in `on_click` or is it called only once?

Comment: I need it to call once and get the pointer to char array. Then I can get the updated text from anywhere. @AlexanderDmitriev

Comment: However, I managed it as passing GtkEntry* to my structure though it is not very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very obvious from [the docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntryBuffer.html#gtk-entry-buffer-get-text), but when you somehow modify text it may be moved to another location, making previous pointer invalid.

If you don't want to pass GtkEntries to your structures, you can update pointers when `EntryBuffer` emits `"deleted-text"` or `"inserted-text"` (or connect to GtkEntry's `"notify::text"`)